# How can we list the tables in HBase created/modified after a particular date/time?

Tags: hbase, hdfs, nosql

I am trying to write a backup script of HBase tables. So I wanted to get all those tables which are created/modified after a particular time. Is there any command for that? Thanks for the suggestions in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### All hbase tables are stored in HDFS

In hbase site.xml see `hbase.rootdir`

```
<property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://hadoop:8020/apps/hbase</value>
 </property>
```

so you can do `hadoop fs -ls -R | grep yourtable`

it will print time stamps